# jQuery UI .autocomplete()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have autocomplete working on my site with the following:

```
$(function () {
    $("#client").autocomplete({
        source: "/appointments/clients.json",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('input[name="clientid"]').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#app-submit').html('Add Appointment for ' + ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```

What I want to do now is that when a user types in something that is not shown on the dropdown, I'd like for the following to take place:

```
$('input[name="clientid"]').val('');
$('#app-submit').html('Add Appointment');
```

I tried using the following but it didn't work:

```
$(function () {
    $("#client").autocomplete({
        source: "/appointments/clients.json",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if(typeof(ui.item)){
                $('input[name="clientid"]').val(ui.item.id);
                $('#app-submit').html('Add Appointment for ' + ui.item.value);
            } else {
                $('input[name="clientid"]').val('');
                $('#app-submit').html('Add Appointment');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the select evevnt is only triggered when you select an item in dropdown
you could do it on `search event`

```
$(function () {
    $("#client").autocomplete({
        source: "/appointments/clients.json",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('input[name="clientid"]').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#app-submit').html('Add Appointment for ' + ui.item.value);
        },
        search: function() {
            $('input[name="clientid"]').val('');
            $('#app-submit').html('Add Appointment');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the whole idea is without seeing markup. But my guess is:

```
$("#client").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/appointments/clients.json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( data ) {
                var suggestions = $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.value,
                        value: item.id
                    }
                });
                // idea: whatever I have, extend to extra item.
                suggestions.push({
                    label: 'Add appointment',
                    value: 0
                });
                response( suggestions );
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(evt, ui){
        if( ui.item.label == 'Add appointment'){
            /* do something special with it */
        }else{
            /* blah blah */
        }
    }
});
```